# How to make a global variable in configuration file

Tags: java, gwt, configuration-files, web.xml

I'd like to pass a value from GWT client side to server side (Servlet).
This variable is filled on click event.
If I create a public property in client side,  it is always null on server side.

So my question is: is it possible to make global this variable, for example in a configuration file (such as web.xml)? Are there any solution as an alternative of configuration files?

Thank you.

Comment: global meaning shared by client and server?

Comment: Yes @KalpeshSoni. Shared or always visible.

Comment: you have two jvms running, one on client, one on server, there is nothing shared between them

Comment: With RPC call I can pass value from server to client as write here http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html, is it possible vice versa?

Comment: the page says gwt rpc stuff runs on client as javascript, i have no experience with that, but yes in general you can write a ping kind of mechanism with thread, call rest api and "sync" data (refresh your value)

Answer (score 0):

In GWT there is strict separation between client side and server side. You need to use an RPC call to pass data between them.

I'd suggest adding a `ClickHandler` or a `ChangeHandler` to the element showing the variable (say the a `TextBox`) which then fires an RPC call to update the server side value.